# Quick question on disenfectants sprays and how some family members are using it

Tags: side-effects

Some of my family members seem to be using Lysol surface disinfectant spray to mask bad odor in the bathroom. I keep trying to explain to them that it's not meant to be used in such a way. They seem to be a firm believer that because it says "removes odor" on it it means it *will* mask odors in the air the same way as actuall air freshener. Every time they spray ALOT. Enough to make me start coughing in a vented room. Anyone have any negative medical health hazard facts I should tell them to make them stop?

Comment: My condolences to you. I'll take poopy smells any day over the chemical warfare people insist on engaging in.

Comment: Welcome to Health, user13086! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research revealed to you on this so far? You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!